# Instr function not case sensitive in LibreOffice basic?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I am writing a function in LibreOffice basic to find position of a character in a string:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Const Source = "abcdefghijklmnopwrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Function GetPos(Char As String) As Integer

GetPos = InStr(Source, Char)

End Function
```

And I am calling it from spreadsheet using =GetPos("M") or =GetPos("m") from a cell in the spreadsheet.  Both are returning 13.

According to the [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/InStr_Function_Runtime), there is a parameter which is used to specify whether it should be case sensitive or not (0 or 1).  If I specify the parameter, I am getting error "Action not supported. Invalid procedure call".

Any idea how to achieve search within string that is case sensitive?

PS: I am using LibreOffice vanilla Version: 5.2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/71560/calc-macro-case-sensitive-instr-not-working/)

It appears that all optional parameters need to be passed, such as:

```
Instr(1, Source, Char, 0)
```